# Why am I getting a NoMethodError when I use Mocha 0.9.8 with Test::Unit 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, testunit, ruby-mocha

Has anyone seen this? Here's the error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -rrubygems -e "require 'redgreen'"  -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "['test/unit', 'test/test_authentication.rb'].each { |f| require f }" | /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/autotest-4.3.2/bin/unit_diff -u
Load/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mocha-0.9.8/lib/mocha/integration/test_unit/gem_version_201_and_above.rb:31:in `run': undefined method `handle_exception' for #<TestAuthentication:0x101823988> (NoMethodError)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:34:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:33:in `each'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:33:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:34:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:33:in `each'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:33:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:46:in `run_suite'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:67:in `start_mediator'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:41:in `start'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/testrunnerutilities.rb:29:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:216:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:12:in `run'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit.rb:278
 from -e:2
ed suite -e
Started
```

And this is the code that triggers that error:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mocha'

require 'authentication'
class TestAuthentication < Test::Unit::TestCase
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the HEAD version of Mocha, but has not yet been released. I hope to release it soon. Please email the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mocha-developer/) if it has not been released in the next few days.